# How to add annotation on map overlay ios

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mapkit

How we can add a pin on map overlay like we add on map??

i am creating an overlay using following code

```
MKOverlayView* overlayV = [[MKOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:mMapView.frame];
[mMapView addOverlay:overlayV.overlay];
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the pin separately to the map view, via

```
[mMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: i need to keep pin fixed at map center thats why i want to add on map overlay not on map.so thats why i asked hoe to add pin on map overlay

Comment: I don't believe you can add a pin to an overlay. You can add an annotation at the map center... unless I am not understanding your question.